# Ubuntu repo on CentOS using debmirror. Client says package missing, but it's there

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, software-sources

I am in a situation that I have to try to server an Ubuntu repo off of a CentOS server (don't ask).  Anyway, I'm using deb mirror and it looks like it grabbed all the packages and stuff (about 155GB worth) for xenial x64 (all I care about). If I do a side by side comparison between my mirror and the actual archive.ubuntu.com repo it looks good and I can traverse the mirror.

From the Ubuntu client if I do a apt-get update, I get this [output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23827879/) And when I do a apt-get install for a package (example aptitude), it says not there, but it's clearly there.

[image]

My sources file on the client looks ok to me?
I just replaced archive.ubuntu.com with my mirror host.

Comment: Please include the output of `apt-get update` (no screenshots of text - copy the text here and use code-formatting)

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (≥100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the output of the apt-get update command. https://paste.ubuntu.com/23827879/                                                                                I also tried downloading the i386 packages as well as I saw some other posts that said this worked for them. It did not.

Comment: Doing some more digging, the output of my apt-get update shows IGN for the xenial main amd64 packages. I assume this is the problem, but why is it ignoring them?